# How to tell the difference between user-agent of outlook 2003(or earlier) and IE open?

Tags: email, outlook, user-agent

When I use webbug technique to track email opens and detect email client, I was able to tell the outlook version by user-agent string, but only for outlook 2007 and later. (by keycode MSOFFICE 12 and MSOFFICE 14)
When I look at the string for outlook 2003, and compare with the open on IE browser, it looks very similar.
Is there any keyword to tell the difference between those two user-agent strings?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't tell from the user-agent String. On an old Windows XP virtual machine with Outlook 2003 and IE 8 installed, I get those two string:

**Outlook 2003:**

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
```

**Internet Explorer 8:**

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
```

**What you might do:**

Add an image inside of a conditional comment, only targeting outlook 2003 and track this image additionally to your other tracking. Then you might combine the two of them to identify old Outlook versions.

Or you have to treat all IE7 user-agent strings as Outlook 2003 asuming, that it is much more likely, that a user is using an old Outlook 2003 version than using the IE7 to view your emails.